# Get conversations and messages. The conversation with last unread message should be on top

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, codeigniter

I've three tables:
conversations, messages, and user.

Explanation of Tables is here.
Conversations table:

```
id
user1
user2
```

Messages table:

```
id
conversation_id
fromUser
toUser
is_read
```

User table:

```
id
name
etc
```

Now, I want to get the conversations of specific user-id let's say 210. and conversations with an unread message should be on top.

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:
The query that I'm firing right now is:

```
SELECT * FROM `messages`
join conversations on messages.conversation_id = conversations.id
where messages.fromUser = 210 or messages.toUser = 210
GROUP by messages.conversation_id
ORDER by messages.is_read ASC, messages.id DESC
```

Result that I'm getting:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEeMs.png

Expected result based conversation id:

```
2
8
1724
and then others.
```

Comment: If you at least post the query, which will return an unordered result, then someone might write a suitable ORDER BY clause for you.

Comment: Hi, @PaulSpiegel, Now I've edited the question, please check if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as adding `ORDER BY is_read, id DESC` to your database query.

We can't help any more as you have not provided anything for us to work with.

Comment: `is_read DESC` may not be correct. If the field is of type `ENUM` it'll depend on the internal `ENUM` index. (creating the field as `ENUM('Y','N')` is not the same as `ENUM('N','Y')` in terms of how it responds to the `order by` clause

Comment: Anything coming after the primary key in the ORDER BY clause is pointless.

Comment: Hi there, I've edited my the question. Please have a look again. And please see if you can help me with something.

Comment: @JavierLarroulet No, it is not an enum type, it is int type.

Comment: @ParvezMemon what value would a read/unread message have for `is_read`? 1 and 0 or something along those lines?

Comment: @JavierLarroulet Yes, it would be 1 for read and 0 for unread.

Answer (score 0):

In case if anyone needs this, I've got the solution working.

```
SELECT * 
FROM conversations 
JOIN 
(SELECT conversation_id, is_read, fromUser, toUser, MAX(id) as id FROM messages GROUP BY messages.id) message 
ON message.conversation_id = conversations.id
WHERE conversations.user1 = 210 or conversations.user2 = 210
GROUP by conversations.id
ORDER by is_read = 0 desc, toUser !=210
```